# How do I access an array from my shopController in my cartController to display all items (and remove if desired)?

Tags: angularjs

I can't figure out how to share an array between two controllers. One
controller is meant to fill the array and the other presents the data and 
allows the user to remove items from the array.

The structure of my
files
are:

```
templates/cart.html 

templates/shop.html 

app.js

index.html
```

---

I have tried route service.

I expect to be able to push user input into an array in the
 "shopController" and present that info in a template using a second
 controller called "cartController" and allow users to remove items if
 desired.

### app.js

```js
//reference routing in order to route and render templates
var myApp=angular.module("myApp", []); 

//create the the routing for the app
myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider){

        $routeProvider.
            when('/shop', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/shop.html',
                controller: 'shopController',
                //items: array
            }).
            when('/cart', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/cart.html',
                controller: 'cartController',
                //items: array
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/shop'
            });

    }]);
//factory that holds data that can be shared between controllers
myApp.service('CartContents', function(){
    //var that should hold all user input
    var privateCart = [];

    var additem = function(newitem){
        privateCart.push(newitem);
    };

    var viewCart = function(){
        return privateCart;
    };

    return {
        additem: additem,
        viewCart: viewCart
    };
});


myApp.controller('cartController', function($scope, CartContents){
    $scope.message = "Cart Page";
    /*call the factory function viewCart in order to view all contents of the array*/
    $scope.items = CartContents.viewCart();
    
});

//contrller functions that manage what each page/template does
myApp.controller('shopController', function($scope, CartContents){
    $scope.message = "Shopping Page";
    $scope.items = CartContents.viewCart();
    /*call the factory function additem in order to push currItem into an array*/
    $scope.selectOrder = function(currItem){
        CartContents.additem(currItem);
        $scope.items = CartContents.viewCart();
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="en">
    <head>
        <title>Simple Web App</title>
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <style>
                body {
                  padding-top: 10px;
                  background-color: #F5F5F5;
                }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="myApp">                                          <!--Angulars way of declaring a root element of the app-->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-1">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a href="#shop">Shop</a></li>   <!--Refrence the .html files that will be separate pages-->
                        <li><a href="#cart">View Order</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div ng-view></div>                          <!--.html templates will be rendered here-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

### cart.html

```html
<h1> Cart Page </h1>
{{message}}

<div ng-model = "cartContents">
    <ul>
        <!--angular loops and displays every string in an array-->
        <li ng-repeat="item in items"> {{item}} </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### shop.html

```html
<h1> Shopping Page </h1>
{{message}}

<div class = "selectItem">
    <input type="text" ng-model="currItem" placeholder = "Select Item">
    <!--basically cal the function selectorder() in my app.js file to add an item-->
    <button ng-click="selectOrder(currItem)">Select</button>
    <ul>
        <!--angular loops and displays every string in an array-->
        <li ng-repeat="item in items"> {{item}} </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a service to pass information from one controller to another.

```
myApp.service('exampleService', function() {
    this.cartContents = [];

    this.addContents = function(newObj) {
      cartContents.push(newObj);
    };

    this.getContents = function(){
        return cartContents;
    };
}
```

Then you would want to dependency inject the service into each controller. In one controller, you would add to the array via the service. In another, you would get the array from the service.

```
myApp.controller('cartController', function($scope, exampleService, /*$route*/CartContents){
    $scope.message = "Cart Page";
    var items = exampleService.getContents();
    $scope.checkout = CartContents.viewCart();

});
myApp.controller('shopController', function($scope, exampleService, /*$route*/CartContents){
    $scope.message = "Shopping Page";
    //var items = $route.current.items;
    $scope.selectOrder = function(currItem){
        CartContents.additem(currItem);
    };
    exampleService.addContents(CartContents);
});
```

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: After making the edits, my "{{message}}" functionality was lost in both shop.html and cart.html and the items are still not being added to the array (or perhaps just not displayed properly). Perhaps my html is incorrect?

Comment: @dsafaro are you getting any errors at all? Can you further explain what you mean by your functionality was lost? Also, make sure you're passing the object as a parameter to the function. ng-click="selectOrder(obj)", then it should get added

Comment: So I got the cart contents to display in the shopping page, but not in the cart. I used the method given to me by answer one. Any tips? Thank you!

Comment: @dsafaro sorry I am just now getting back to you. It looks like you have ng-model bound to a div and the model is the service you created. In order to access a service directly in the DOM, you need to set a scope variable to the service. For example: $scope.cartContents = CartContents.

In addition to this.. I can't really see if you have done it yet but try using ng-controller on your cart and set it to the cartController. Let me know if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The shopping page is missing an argument:

```
<h1> Shoping Page </h1>
{{message}}

<div class = "selectItem">
    <input type="text" ng-model="currItem" placeholder = "Select Item">
    ̶<̶b̶u̶t̶t̶o̶n̶ ̶n̶g̶-̶c̶l̶i̶c̶k̶=̶"̶s̶e̶l̶e̶c̶t̶O̶r̶d̶e̶r̶(̶)̶"̶>̶S̶e̶l̶e̶c̶t̶<̶/̶b̶u̶t̶t̶o̶n̶>̶
    <button ng-click="selectOrder(currItem)">Select</button>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Also its controller needs to get the `items` from the service:

```
myApp.controller('shopController', function($scope, /*$route*/CartContents){
    $scope.message = "Shopping Page";
    ̶/̶/̶v̶a̶r̶ ̶i̶t̶e̶m̶s̶ ̶=̶ ̶$̶r̶o̶u̶t̶e̶.̶c̶u̶r̶r̶e̶n̶t̶.̶i̶t̶e̶m̶s̶;̶
    $scope.items = CartContents.viewCart();

    $scope.selectOrder = function(currItem){
        CartContents.additem(currItem);
        $scope.items = CartContents.viewCart();
    };
});
```

Comment: The cart now ads to the array and displays those contents in shopping, but the communication between controllers doesn't seem to work. Any ideas as to why?